# Tiny UI on ubuntu with wsl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server, mobaxterm

I installed ubuntu on windows using WSL (windows subsystem for linux). I was able to install vscode and firefox via app-get install but when I launch them, they have very tiny UI and fonts. I am using Mobaxterm and I'm new to all these stuff

Windows 10 Home, Version 1803
Screen resolution: 4k
X server: WSL-ubuntu

I have tried using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 2`.

I have also tried changing the settings with gnome-tweak-tools. None worked

[image]

Comment: Did you try X-Server or VcxSrv in Windows?

Comment: I tried VcxSrv, but it had the same issue. I haven't tried X-server